# How to split a line by space [.split( )], but keep a specific space

Tags: python

I have a text file which I need to split. Normally, I could use line.split() to separate parts of the line by empty space. However, in this case, part of the string I need contains a space which needs to be ignored when splitting...

The text file looks something like this:

1   Qatar   $            98,900

2   United States   $            95,000

3   Luxembourg  $            80,600

4   Bermuda $            69,900

5   Singapore   $            59,700

6   Jersey  $            57,000

7   Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)   $            55,400

I need each country to be considered one 'part'. But of course when I use the line.split() separator, python wants to split up at each space.

How can I keep multi-worded country names (like 'United States' and 'Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)' together as one part?

I have tried the simple line.split() method. I have also looked for ways to strip out the digit at the beginning of the line (with an .lstrip or something) and then split the line by the '$' symbol (I also need to collect the dollar value as another part) but have had no luck in this regard.

```
for line in file:
    part = line.split()
```

The desire is to be able to use the 'part' variable to collect the country name and its corresponding value with 'part[1]' and 'part[3]' and input them to a dictionary as a corresponding key-value pair. So the final output would look something like this:

dict = {'Qatar': '98,900', 'United States': '95,000',... 'Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)': '55,400'}

Comment: Does your text always look like this? Index, Name, Currency, Amount?

Comment: Consider Regex or you will have a Hard time !

Comment: Are there values with less of more spaces?

Comment: Would it be correct to say that everything before the dollar sign will be the key, and everything after, the value?

Comment: 1. Split by first space using line.split(" ", 1) 2. Split resulting second part by substring ' $ '. This should return ['United States', '95000'] which can be converted to dictionary

Comment: Is it always about the US? Or could it be anything you don't know about? If the latter, you will generally have a hard time, with or without regex, if you don't find other splitting rules than pure spaces. (Costa Rica, Sierra Leone, Alpha Centauri...?)

Comment: I have updated the post with a larger example of the text file and expounded on what it is I'm looking to do!

Comment: Perhaps a simpler question is this... Stack overflow reformats my question so that the spaces don't properly show when I give the example of my text file, but in the actual text file there are multiple spaces between each part of the line. Is there a way to say split by telling python "if there is more than one space between parts of the line, split there"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dict((line.split(" ", 1)[1].split(" $ "),))
{'United States': '95,000'}
```

Or to add this to an existing dictionary `mydict`

```
mydict.update(dict((line.split(" ", 1)[1].split(" $ "),)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of 'United States' as a proper noun, and convert each proper noun into a whole before splitting the string:

```py
>>> convert={'United States': 'UnitedStates'}
>>> text = '1 United States $ 95,000'
>>> text = text.replace('United States',convert['United States'])
>>> text
'1 UnitedStates $ 95,000'
```

Recover them after the split is complete:

```py
>>> recover = {v: k for k, v in convert.items()}
>>> parts = [recover.get(i, i) for i in text.split()]
>>> parts
['1', 'United States', '$', '95,000']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lines in your text file always consist of the four items index, country, currency symbol and amount of money, you could do:

```
for line in file:
    left, curr, value = line.rsplit(' ', 2)
    country = left.split(' ', 1)[1]

    # print(country, ': ', value)
# United States :  95000
```